# Spring boot admin server configuration on Cloud run

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We have a few cloud run services deployed on Cloud run with **Ingress control** set to "**All**" and **Authentication** set to "**IAM**". These are REST APIs created using Spring boot framework. We have one more Cloud Run service which is deployed as Spring boot admin server with **Ingress control** set to "**All**" and **Authentication** set to "**Allow Unauthenticated Invocations**".

Now the backend team have configured the Cloud run REST API services with the following cloud run endpoints in ***application.properties*** to communicate with Spring boot admin server:-

```
spring.boot.admin.client.url=${sm://cloud_run_rest_api_endpoint}
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-url=${sm://spring_boot_admin_server_cloud_run_endpoint}
```

This obviously fails on cloud run with **403 Unauthorized** as the endpoints (Eg: /health, /metrics, /trace etc) required by Spring boot admin server from its clients need an **Authorization Bearer token**.

Is it possible to pass JWT token when accessing those endpoints ? Has anyone had success in setting up the same ? Or is there any possibility to have some of our cloud run service endpoints to be public on which we can later apply some security provided by spring ?

We are in the middle of setting up free API monitoring tool for our all APIs. Any recommendations are much appreciated.

Comment: Regarding the possibility of having some of your Cloud Run service endpoints to be public on which you can later apply some security provided by Spring, one approach would be to use a reverse proxy such as Cloud Endpoints or Apigee to expose only the endpoints that need to be public, and then apply security provided by Spring on those endpoints.

Comment: Or API Gateway. You can't filter endpoint by endpoint with Cloud IAM. You need an additional layer.